# Change a specific input's css elements

Tags: html, css, input

```
<div id="right-side-panel">
        <span>UserName:<br />
        <input id="txtUserName" type="text" />
        </span>
        <br />
        <span>Password:<br />
        <input id="txtPassword" type="password" />
        </span>
        <br />        
        <input id="btnLogin" type="button" value="Login" />
        </div>
```

How can I reach this txtUserName from css file? I want to change textBox's things.

`#right-side-panel` .. then?

Thanks in advance

Comment: just #txtUserName ? Edit: come on guys, you've got to be kidding... all you need is the #txtUserName!

Comment: I thought this was a trick-question when I first read it

Comment: It would be nice to have a -1 on the first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:
in css
`#txtUserName {
color:black;
}`

in jQuery
`$('#txtUserName').css('color', 'black');`

Answer (score 1):

The W3C defines IDs as "a unique identifiers to an element", so you just need `#txtUserName` in order to match that `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you just do: `input#txtUserName?`